# Spring boot JPA how to query a @OneToMany relationship given one object in the many relationship

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I've seen a few related questions but I can't seem to find the right answer for what I'm trying to do.
I have two tables Jobs and Workers, a job can have many workers, simplified entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jobs")
data class Job(
    @Id
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()
) {
    @ManyToOne
    var office: Office? = null

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Worker::class)
    var requests: MutableList<Worker> = mutableListOf()
}
```

I want to be able to fetch a list of jobs for a specific worker

I've tried a few queries native and not, but trying to just do it by namedMethods now, whatever works I guess to be honest here is what seems like it should work in my jobs repo

```
@Repository
interface JobsRepo : CrudRepository<Job, UUID> {

    @Query("SELECT j FROM Job j WHERE id = ?1")
    fun findJobById(id: UUID): Job?

    @Query("SELECT j FROM Job j WHERE office_id = ?1")
    fun findJobsByOffice(id: UUID): List<Job>?

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("UPDATE jobs SET job_status = 4 WHERE job_status = 1 AND start_time < ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    fun expireJobs(date: Date)

    fun findByRequests_Worker(worker: Worker): List<Job>?

}
```

I'm not really sure how to query the array property

```
requests
```

with in input of one worker. I tried querying the UUID of the worker too since thats whats in the join table

JPA creates a join table with both foreign keys the table is

```
jobs_requests
```

and columns

```
job_id UUID
requests_id UUID
```

Comment: Could you show us your database mapping for the entites and their relationships?

Comment: What about your database scripts?

Comment: There are no DB scripts hiberante is doing all of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that a Job can have many workers, and you also mentioned that you want to get a list of jobs for a specific worker. So this sounds like a ManyToMany relationship rather than OneToMany.

For a ManyToMany relationship, a join table is unavoidable. You need to specify @ManyToMany annotation on both entities, then you can use WorkerRepository to query for the worker and then to get the job list for that worker you will just need to access by worker.getJobs().

Following is the setup for the ManyToMany relationship, hope it can help:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "jobs")
data class Job (
    @ManyToMany
    @get:ManyToMany
    @get:JoinTable(
            name = "worker_job",
            joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "job_id")],
            inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "worker_id")]
    )
    val worker: Set<Worker> = HashSet()

)
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "worker")
data class Worker (
    @ManyToMany
    @get:ManyToMany
    @get:JoinTable(
            name = "worker_job",
            joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "worker_id")],
            inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "job_id")]
    )
     val jobs: Set<Jobs> = HashSet()
)
```

Comment: manytomany seems to have made it work, but it doesn't make a lot of sense, one job can have many workers but only for that job. On the other side yes workers will have many jobs, maybe i'm missing the manytomany idea. Entity mapping is new to me, but given the extra sql you added why would it ever be manytomany. One job has an array of workers, OneToMany perhaps I'm thinking about it wrong. Also I dont define the worker object as bi directional, could that be a problem. Last question do sets, lists, or mutabale lists make a difference how the tables are built.

Comment: 'one job can have many workers' - which means `Job -> Worker` is a to-many association. 'workers will have many jobs' - which means `Worker -> Job` is a to-many association. Add that together and you get a many-to-many association. It would be a one-to-many association if, for instance, a worker could only have one job

Comment: @crizzis made a good explanation why it's a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: as for the differences between list and set, you don't have to worry about duplicate items in set, why list allows duplicated elements. 

For mutable list, it is a list that you can read and modify, where immutable lists only allow you to read. Similar for set and mutable/immutable sets. The code snippet above uses HashSet, which is an implementation of ImmutableSet.

Answer (score 0):

Its also worth noting that for all practical uses, you should try to avoid explicit ManyToMany annotation. You should rather make a new Entity/Table which will have fields of a Job and Worker both with ManyToOne associations to their respective entities.

The reason why you should avoid explicit ManyToMany is because, say when there is a specific job for example **JavaDev**, and there are say 1000 **Workers** on the given job. And at one point you have a **JavaDev** entity and you want to get all the workers whose ages are between 20 and 25. To do this, one would iterate on the **Workers** list which is part of **JavaDev** entity and filter them out. When that happens there is 2 scenarios:

1. **Workers** list is a lazy association and when you try to access it hibernate will send 1000(n+1 problem) queries to the database.
2. **Workers** list is an eager association and hibernate will send same amount of queries to the database but as soon as you try to fetch **JavaDev** entity.

Hence your execution times will increase as there will be unnecessary amount of load on the database itself. And on larger projects this will get even more complicated.

All of this can be avoided if you create your own manytomany(job_workers for ex.) table, with accompanying repository and a service, from witch you'll be able to query your data more efficiently.